# Help with creating a new JAXB instance in Oracle enterprise manager

Tags: java, jaxb, classloader

When trying to create a new JAXB instance inside a servlet I am getting a JAXBException saying the jaxb.properties cannot be found.  I have been trying to explicitly pass the classloader with the call to JAXBContext.newInstance() but I cannot figure it out.

Here are the class loaders:

```
servlet classloader:    oc4j:10.1.3  
servlet parent classloader:     api:1.4.0  
this classloader:   RestTest.web.ExampleWebApp:0.0.0  
this classloader parent: RestTest.root:0.0.0
```

The JAXB generated classes are in a different package, so my servlet is in package "com.xyz.ws" and the JAXB classes are in package "com.abc.123".  I am creating the new JAXB instance from the servlet with `

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("com.abc.123", servletClassLoader)
```

(I also tried using `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this fixes the issue (found [here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=15909&tstart=60)):

> Step 1 : Copy the JAXB2.0 jars to D:\dev\oc4j10.1.3.0.0\j2ee\home\applib (D:\dev\oc4j10.1.3.0.0 is my oc4j installation location)
>   (j2ee\home\applib This directory is placeholder for common library files for all projects (deployed applications)
>   Files which were added were
>   jaxb-api-2.0.jar, jaxb-impl-2.0.jar, jsr173_api-1.0.jar (JAXB2.0 jars can be found at http://jaxb.java.net/)
>
> Step2: When deploying Application via Enterprise Manager (WebBrowser) change the deployment plan.
>
> 2.1 You can change deplyoment plan on the last step (screen) of depolyment by clicking on a BUTTON saying Edit Deployment plan.
>
> 2.2 On clicking the BUTTON Application sepcific properties are displayed. Select link importedLibraries (Edit importedLibraries) and then CLICK Edit Remove link enter name oracle.xml and click continue and finish the deployment.
>
> The reason of the error is xml.jar (JAXB 1.0) which is present as shared libaray in variable name oracle.xml (see Enterprise Manager->Administration-> Shared Libraries.
>
> What we achieved from above steps is removing default (old version of JAXB) for our application and forcing OC4J to read newer JAXB2.0 implementation (jars)

Answer (score 1):

Well is there a jaxb.properties file in the `com.abc.123` package? JAXB needs one to build the context.

Comment: I am using JAXB 2.1 (in the /WEB-INF/lib folder) and it's not supposed to require a jaxb.properties, but maybe the oc4j library is using JAXB 1.0 and there's a conflict.  I will have to look into it.